# Discord.py How to add a role to user in server who DMs the bot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have only seen DiscordJS tutorials on this topic.
Right now I have coded only this bit and don't know how to move on.

```
if isinstance(message.channel, discord.channel.DMChannel) and message.author != client.user:
       
    user_id = message.message.author.id

    member = bot.get_user(user_id)

    role = '<role_id>'
    server = '<server_id>'
            
    await bot.members(server).get_user(user_id).add_roles(role)

else:
    return
```

Obviously this doesn't work. Any help is useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess this should work.. write a comment if it doesn't

```py
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.members
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='PREFIX', intents=intents, case_insensitive=True)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if isinstance(message.channel, discord.channel.DMChannel) and message.author != client.user:
        guild = client.get_guild(SERVER_ID) # Has to be int
    
        member = guild.get_member(message.author.id)

        role = guild.get_role(ROLE_ID) # Also has to be int

        member.add_roles(role)

    else:   # If you ain't got any code after this you can delete the else
        return
```

---

[Intents.members](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents.members)

[commands.Bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot)

[on_message Event](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message)

[bot.get_guild](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_guild)

[guild.get_member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_member)

[guild.get_role](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_role)

[member.add_roles](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles)

Comment: Also make sure to enable the `members` Intent.

Comment: Thanks, this works. You're a legend!

Comment: You're welcome, but don't forget to mark it as correct :)